# Where can I watch Zettai Karen Children, or old anime in general?

Tags: resources, zettai-karen-children

Well, the truth is, I haven't been reading manga lately, and the first thing that I remember is Zettai Karen Children. Following that, Haibane Renmei, and Aria, etc.

Problem is, I can't find anyone selling them anymore. Where can I buy or watch them?

I'd like legal resources as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Some legal and popular anime streaming sites are:

- [**Crunchyroll**](https://www.crunchyroll.com)
- [**Manga Entertainment**](http://www.manga.com/)
- [**Funimation**](http://www.funimation.com/watch)
- [**Daisuki**](https://www.daisuki.net)
- [**The Anime Network**](http://www.theanimenetwork.com)

The anime you're looking for, *Zettai Karen Children*, can be found on [The Anime Network](http://www.theanimenetwork.com/Anime/Psychic-Squad/Info), and the spin-off series *The Unlimited - Hyōbu Kyōsuke* can be found on [Crunchyroll](http://www.crunchyroll.com/the-unlimited-hyobu-kyosuke).

As for the manga(s), [**Amazon**](http://www.amazon.com/Manga-Comics-Graphic-Novels-Books/b?ie=UTF8&node=4367) is a good place to start.

<sub>Here's a [list of legal anime streaming/download sites](http://www.reddit.com/r/anime/wiki/legal_streams_/_downloads).</sub>

Comment: Ah, I mean the old ones. The 2008-2009 series. Sadly, no ones ever uploaded to any of them.
Amazon don't have the manga, and I can't open reddit (country's firewall) but thank you for the answer. I think that I need to go to japan to hunt for this thing.

Comment: @user14064 which country are you from? Knowing the country can help finding out the availability of anime/manga in that region.